# UML diagram for an existing implementation

Tags: uml, design, class-diagram

I have some code, which I want to present in UML, but I've stuck at one point.
Let me tell you something about code's functionality.

I have a workspace in which I can place some `Component`s, select them, delete, add new, move etc. I can also connect them according to some rules (there are different types of `Component`s available). In order to determine if a group of `Component`s can be connected or not, I've implemented some easy mechanism. In this mechanism the following parts appear:

*[**EDIT**: Please note, that "PlausibilityRule" in UML and "ConnectionRule" are the same things - it's my oversight]*

**`ConnectionRule`** - get the type of connection, and checks if a collection of `Component`s given as a parameter can be connected according to this `ConnectionRule`.

**`ConnectionRulesSet`** - has many rules inside. Client asks a set with rules like this: "according to which rules definied in a set, components given as a parameter, can be connected"? `ConnectionRulesSet` gives a list of `ConnectionRules` as a response. A concrete Connection rules set are exposed only throug interface - Client cannot create an instance of a concrete RulesSet.

**`RulesSetFactory`** - depending on many circumstances, application can use different `ConnectionRulesSet`s. That's why I've created a factory which gives a proper implemetation of `ConnectionRulesSet` interface depending on specified circumstances.

And now let's take a look at the Client's code:

```
// list of components which should be verified in terms of connection plausibility:
List<Component> selectedComponents = ... ;
// Get set of rules for normal conditions:
ConnectionRulesSet setOfRules = RulesSetFactory.getRulesSet(NORMAL_SET);
List<ConnectionRule> fulfilledRules = setOfRules.getFulfilledRules(final selectedComponents);
// Do something with fulfilled rules:
for(PlausibilityRule rule : fulfilledRules){
   addToAvailableRulesList(rule.getConnectionType().getName()); // display names of connetion types...
}
```

My problem is, that I'm not sure how to create an UML class diagram for such solution from Client's perspective... How to expose relationships between presented solution and a Client. Client uses actually all: ConnectionRule, RulesSet, RulesSetFactory...

There is one of my ideas below... What do you think? Have you got any better solution?

[image: Sample UML class diagram]

Comment: It looks like some of the interface names in your UML diagram don't match up with the explanation in your question?  Is `PlausibilityRule` the same concept as `ConnectionRule`?  If not: a) What *is* the difference? and b) Where is `ConnectionRule` (as opposed to `ConnectionRulesSet`) in the diagram?

Comment: @Tersosauros Yeah, you are certainly right - PlausibilityRule and ConnectionRule are the same things - my oversight

Comment: So then, is a `ConnectionRulesSet` _just_ an aggregation/composition of `ConnectionRule`'s?  Or is there more responsibility meant by the `ConnectionRulesSet` having the _behavior_ to `getFulfilledRules`?

Comment: @Tersosauros Actually it aggregates all Rules and, using the getFulfilledRules method, returns only those which are reasonable for components given as a parameter (btw, getFulfilledRules() should take a 'comps' parameter, I guess - it seems that this question was not perfectly prepared before asking :/)

Comment: So `ConnectionRulesSet` (which I *believe* under most OOP naming conventions would/should be "`ConnectionRuleSet` " - It's _one_ set, of _zero or more_ `ConnectionRule`'s, not `ConnectionRules`..) - has both a behavioural responsibility (filtering rules), and an aggregation responsibility (being a set of rules)?

Comment: Yes. Exactly as you said.

Comment: I thought creating UML diagrams for existing code was considered to be pointless?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'm going to give this answer a shot - hopefully I've understood everything correctly!

### The Diagram

Firstly, let me apologize in advance for the layout ([yUML](http://yuml.me) is nice and quick, but lays large diagrams out strangely sometimes).
[image: Class diagram (from yUML.me)]

As you can see, there aren't that many changes.  But there are a few, namely:

- Added an aggregation (specifically, a **"**[*composition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#UML_notation)**"**) from `ConnectionRuleSet` to `ConnectionRule`.

  This is more clear, I feel, than the *returns list of* relation in your original diagram (as a `ConnectionRuleSet` is *a set of* `ConnectionRule`'s).  The container relationship reflects the aggregation responsibility of `ConnectionRuleSet`, but **may not explicitly explain the behavioural responsibility of the `getFulfilledRules` method**.
- Removed the *uses* between `Client` and `ConnectionRuleSet`.

  Given the *uses* relation already in-place in-between `Client` and `ConnectionRule` directly, adding another *uses* between `Client` and `ConnectionRuleSet` I feel needlessly overcomplicates things.  It's clear that a  `ConnectionRuleSet` *contains*  `ConnectionRule`'s (thanks to the composition).
- Added a `Component` class to the diagram.

  I'm not 100% sure exactly what a `Component` is in your domain, however I think it **might** be worth it to include it in the diagram.  After all, it is *mentioned* in methods in `ConnectionRule` and `ConnectionRuleSet`.  It is not entirely clear from your question what the relation between `Client` and `Component` should be, I've used aggregation as it seems a `Client` *contains* many `Component`'s.

---

### Other Diagram Notes

1. **Example concrete classes**:  I think the example concrete classes, such as `ConcreteConnectionRuleSet`, `ConcreteRule1` and `ConcreteRule2`, etc **add very little** to the diagram.  I've included them as they were in the original, but I think the diagram would be much simpler without them.
2. **Vector<Component>**:  Again, included as it was in the original, but I would **STRONGLY** recommend that you don't tie your *design* to particular data-structure *implementations* (this goes for List<Component> too!).  Something like [`Collection<Component>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), or at a minimum an [`IList<Component>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) would be much better here.

---

Feel free to [go on to yUML](http://yuml.me) and [edit the diagram](http://yuml.me/edit/2c9912f9)... Below is the code [yUML](http://yuml.me) code I used to make it:

```
[«interface»;RuleSetFactory|+ getRuleSet(rulseSetType : enum)]-.-                 «instantiates»-.->[«interface»;ConnectionRuleSet|getFulfilledRules(comps : List≤Component≥)]
[«interface»;ConnectionRuleSet]++-[«interface»;ConnectionRule|+ getConnectionType();+ isFulfilledForComponents(comps : Vector≤Component≥)]
[«interface»;ConnectionRule]<-.-   uses-.-[Client]
[Client]<>-?-[Component]
[Client]-.-requests       RuleSet from-.->[«interface»;RuleSetFactory]
[«interface»;ConnectionRuleSet]^.=[ConcreteConnectionRuleSet]
[«interface»;ConnectionRule]^-.=[ConcreteRule1]
[«interface»;ConnectionRule]^-.=[ConcreteRule2]
```